# How to solve R select problem, using random pivot

Tags: python, list, sorting, select, pivot

I need to find the kth number in the input list. Please tell me what's wrong

---

```
def partition(arr, start, end, pivot):
    pivot_locate = arr.index(pivot)  
    arr[pivot_locate], arr[start] = arr[start], arr[pivot_locate]  
    L = start;    R = end 
    i = L+1;      j = L+1

    for k in range(j, R+1):  #k = 1~R
        if arr[k] < pivot:
            arr[i], arr[k] = arr[k], arr[i]
            i += 1
        j = k

    arr[L], arr[i-1] = arr[i-1], arr[L]

    return arr        



def RSelect(arr, start, end, i):

    if start == end : return arr[start] 
    if start < end :
        pivot = random.choice(arr)  
        while arr.index(pivot) < start or arr.index(pivot) > end :
            pivot = random.choice(arr)
        arr_new = partition(arr, start, end, pivot)

        pLoc = arr_new.index(pivot)
        if pLoc == i : return pivot  
        elif pLoc > i : return RSelect(arr_new, start, pLoc-1, i)  
        else : return RSelect(arr_new, pLoc+1, end, i)



T =int(input())
for j in range(T):
    N, k = map(int, input().split())
    my_list = list(map(int,input().split()))
    k = len(my_list)-k
    anw = RSelect(my_list, 0, len(my_list)-1, k)
    print(anw)
```

Some of the test code works fine, but some outputs incorrect answers. I don't know what's the problem. I am taking a course on the probabilistic selection algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues when the input list contains a lot of duplicate values. These issues all relate to how you use `index()`. You cannot assume that `index()` will return the index of the searched value *within* the range `[start, end]`, even if you know it should be within that range, it could *also* occur outside of it. And as `index()` returns the index of the *first* occurrence, you get undesired results:

- In `partition`, `arr.index(pivot)` could return an index that is less than `start`, which obviously will lead to an undesired swap of the value at `start` to outside the range.
- `while arr.index(pivot) < start` could be true, even if the value is *also* present in the subrange that is under consideration. In case the range consists of *only* repetitions of this value and no other, this will make that `while` loop an infinite loop.
- A similar problem occurs with `arr_new.index(pivot)`. This can lead to a recursive call where the range is *greater* than the current range, leading to a potential stack overflow.

Some other remarks:

- `arr_new = partition()` is a bit misleading, as it gives the impression you get a *new* list, but actually `arr` has been mutated and it is the list that `partition` also returns. So to avoid misinterpretation, it is better to just continue with `arr` and not introduce a new variable for the same list. Instead of returning `arr`, it would be more useful if `partition` would return the *index* of where the pivot value ended up. This way you don't have to perform an `index` call any more.
- `partition` has to search the given pivot value. It can be relieved from that scan by passing it the *index* of the pivot. You should really aim to avoid using `index` at all as it leads to a worse average time complexity.

Here is the proposed code with those points taken into account:

```
def partition(arr, start, end, pivot_locate):
    # The function gets the index, and now gets the pivot value
    pivot = arr[pivot_locate]
    arr[pivot_locate], arr[start] = arr[start], arr[pivot_locate]  
    L = start;    R = end 
    i = L+1;      j = L+1

    for k in range(j, R+1):
        if arr[k] < pivot:
            arr[i], arr[k] = arr[k], arr[i]
            i += 1
        j = k

    arr[L], arr[i-1] = arr[i-1], arr[L]

    return i-1  # return the new index of the pivot        

def RSelect(arr, start, end, i):
    if start >= end:
        return arr[start] 
    if start < end:
        # Select a random index within the range
        pLoc = random.randint(start, end)
        # call partition with that index and get a new index back
        pLoc = partition(arr, start, end, pLoc)

        if pLoc == i: 
            return arr[pLoc] 
        elif pLoc > i:
            return RSelect(arr, start, pLoc-1, i)
        else: 
            return RSelect(arr, pLoc+1, end, i)
```